# How do I do collapsed="false" in this code

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui

I have found this code in here: https://jqueryui.com/accordion/#collapsible

But I do not understand how to do data-collapsed="false" in this code,
This is my full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Accordion - Collapse content</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
            collapsible: true
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div role="tablist" class="ui-accordion ui-widget ui-helper-reset" id="accordion">
    <h3 tabindex="0" data-collapsed="false" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-id-2" id="ui-id-1" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-accordion-icons ui-state-focus ui-corner-all"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 1</h3>
    <div aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" id="ui-id-2" style="display: none; height: 105px;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        <p>Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. 
Integer ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, 
condimentum sit amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. 
Proin viverra leo ut odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu 
ante scelerisque vulputate.</p>
    </div>
    <h3 tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-id-4" id="ui-id-3" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 2</h3>
    <div aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" id="ui-id-4" style="display: none; height: 105px;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        <p>Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit 
amet purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis 
porttitor velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non 
quam. In suscipit faucibus urna. </p>
    </div>
    <h3 tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-id-6" id="ui-id-5" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 3</h3>
    <div aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-id-5" id="ui-id-6" style="display: none; height: 105px;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        <p>Nam enim risus, molestie et, porta ac, aliquam ac, risus. Quisque 
lobortis. Phasellus pellentesque purus in massa. Aenean in pede. 
Phasellus ac libero ac tellus pellentesque semper. Sed ac felis. Sed 
commodo, magna quis lacinia ornare, quam ante aliquam nisi, eu iaculis 
leo purus venenatis dui. </p>
        <ul>
            <li>List item one</li>
            <li>List item two</li>
            <li>List item three</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3 tabindex="-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="ui-id-8" id="ui-id-7" role="tab" class="ui-accordion-header ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-accordion-icons"><span class="ui-accordion-header-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e"></span>Section 4</h3>
    <div aria-hidden="true" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="ui-id-7" id="ui-id-8" style="display: none; height: 105px;" class="ui-accordion-content ui-helper-reset ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom">
        <p>Cras dictum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et 
netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis
 in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean 
lacinia mauris vel est. </p><p>Suspendisse eu nisl. Nullam ut libero. 
Integer dignissim consequat lectus. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad 
litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. </p>
    </div>
</div>




</body></html>
```

The problem is every time I just reload the page it show like this:

[image]

But want like this:
[image]

Please help me, Thank You.

Comment: What if you do `data-collapsed="true"` in your first `h3` tag?

Comment: @D4V1D: That also I try, but not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to amend any HTML at all as the jQueryUI accordion has the `active` property to determine which panel to expand on load. By default it is `0` - the first panel. Set this to `false` to collapse all by default:

```
$("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```

> [Active property docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active)

Comment: Rory McCrossan: But it stop all collapsible?

Comment: Rory McCrossan: sir now it is fully not collapsible? what happen now?

Comment: It should be, here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/pc4dtd1x/ Check the console as you may have errors elsewhere in your code.

Comment: Rary: I want to make cancel button for closing collapsible
can that possible?